# Rollback button in suggested edits queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

> This edit was already approved - please visit the post and correct the edit.

Why? Can't I have a rollback button on the page? Preferably putting the edit into a mod queue to consider review-banning the robo-reviewers? The extra clicking seems unnecessary.

Comment: +1 (mainly) for the part about the mod queue. Somehow it´s really necessary.

Comment: A rollback button without seeing the final edit could be dangerous - the approver could have "improved" the edit and actually made it worthwhile.

Comment: @jrturton Then make the UI show the final edit. Simple.

Comment: Here is an approved edit that could have used the rollback option: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4642203   The user improved the formatting but removed an extra ';' that was the root of the OPs problem.

Comment: Better than showing the final edit: Remove the button if it was improved instead of just accepted. Add a rollback with prejudice option to notify the mods, with mandatory comment. Maybe automatically remove the notification and the rollback if edited within $timespan by the approvers.

Comment: I'm new to [tag:suggested-edits] queue but I'm seeing this time and again, I try to take my time on a review but by the time I cast my vote it's already been approved. It takes time to check the context of a question or answer and any comments there-in. I tend to find myself going through my review history to check the outcome of some votes and correcting bad decisions myself as I come across them.