# My questions have been put On-Hold, what's wrong with them?

Tags: support, closed-questions, help-center

Can someone explain how I can improve my experience in Stack Overflow?  Now that I've learned how Stack Overflow works I think I can use it better, and if I accidentally ask the same question multiple ways I try to change the question/delete them.

Also how do I remove a question from the hold status?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about, can you clarify please? Are you trying to say that you've had some questions put on hold, and you're trying to figure out how to improve them and avoid that in the future? If so, then please [click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: I can see only two of your questions that have been put on hold: one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501430/why-is-flipper-working-incorrectly) and [one here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23502165/revisions)- I don't know if there are others you have deleted. In both cases (in the original revision), you never actually asked a question: you just gave a large amount of code and said "There are issues."

Comment: I also have large ammounts of down votes: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3277047/placeholders-in-use?tab=questions

Comment: I put comments around the buggy code, because I know that the two functions are working, but the flipper is broken for some reason.

Comment: You should really re-read the section on How To Ask in the Help Center.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is your account was frozen (didn't you receive a message with the reason?) because all of your edits are very inappropriate, one [three hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4778580): you changed the title from *"How to instrument a program with macros using clang"* to *"How do I program a macro using the language of C?"* and labeled that edit as *"bad question"*.

What you [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23572253/revisions) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23572771/revisions) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23572803/revisions) [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4772107) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4771886) [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584966/with-firebug-or-other-software-is-there-a-way-to-send-other-variable-values-thr#comment36198037_23584966) to change the titles of questions you don't seem to fully understand, making the titles useless.

You also should not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4705023) or [post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277047/placeholders-in-use?tab=answers) answers where you actually should comment.

Read [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), which will tell you longer titles aren't better, and [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Also, all reviewers are to blame (and review-ban as far as I'm concerned) for accepting those suggestions.

Comment: About the reviewers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251333/rollback-button-in-suggested-edits-queue

Comment: Why isn't there a time frame to lift a ban after someone learns how to use the software better through exploring how others use it?

Comment: Points sometimes take a lot of editing to build I was told.  t's a ban on questions, not edits.

Comment: @13375 maybe because some people will just wait until the ban goes, the only way to know they learnt is through editing, but don't worry, I had an answer ban before but after making my old answers better, my ban was lifted.

Comment: @13375 now I'm question banned and planning to lift it, I cleared many downvotes and had two questions of score 1(maybe not very good but hey , it's a good start).

Comment: @13375 and if your questions/answers are unsalvageable, look at [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280870/what-should-an-user-do-when-hes-in-a-question-ban-with-unsalvageable-questions)

Comment: #niceman I was asking for guidance on making a chatroom with PHP, and the community didn't like it as a full question, nor broken down into pieces.