# What should a user do with unsalvageable questions when they have been question banned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, bad-questions

Let's say a user has posted a lot of really bad questions that can't be improved and has reached the question ban (not the new "throttles" but the actual ban, like back in the old days). What are they supposed to do in this case?

To me it looks like they are stuck, and the only solution would be to create a new account (technically it's circumventing the ban, but as long as the questions from the new account are good I don't think anyone would notice), or to [edit previous questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261172/can-i-get-out-of-a-question-ban-by-editing-my-previous-questions-into-completely) into completely new and better questions, which is also against the rules as per the linked post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The typical recourse for a user in a situation like this is to [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) the team for assistance. When contacting the team, you need to show that you have understood how the site works and are capable of learning from your mistakes and asking better questions. What happens with your account depends on the situation, but usually this can mean either disassociating the absolute worst questions from your account so they no longer contribute to the ban, or if your account is really unsalvageable, they might remove it altogether so you can create a new one.

If a user starts posting good questions on a new account on their own accord, then I guess we'll just allow them to use their new account. The purpose of the question ban, ultimately, is to help users understand how our site works, and if we manage to help them and/or they manage to figure it out, their future positive contributions will be more than welcome.

Most users, however, simply don't learn. If they create new accounts to circumvent the ban only to continue posting low-quality questions, that's where we step in in order to keep them out.

Needless to say, all the other rules regarding having access to more than one account applies. For example, if either account has enough rep to cast votes, it should not be used to vote on the other account.

Comment: 'need to show that you have understood how the site works and are capable of learning from your mistakes and asking better questions' - how often has that happened?  When/if it does, do/will you throw a party?  :)

Comment: @Martin James: At least once.

Comment: The team said we don't do anything about bans. Fix your existing questions. Luckly I got serially upvoted and asked a good question before I got rebanned. The question got upvoted and I am unbanned.

Comment: @2426021684: The ban system has seen a few changes since this answer was posted. You're no longer completely hosed once you hit the ban. At the *bare minimum* you get to ask one question every six months - and just being able to ask one good question is an excellent opportunity to improve your standing.

Comment: @BoltClock I got -9 on my second question. I have four unrepairable questions. I can't delete one of them. Everyone just tells me to fix them but I can't without changing the topic (which is against the rules). Currently one upvote away from being unbanned. Is there a way to delete your account and start over or actually delete questions (no longer effect ban)?

Comment: @BoltClock Is there a way to know when I can post another one with a question ban? (The one every 6 months)