# How can I improve my questions

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban, quality-improvement

I have currently reached my question limit and I get the message 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.'

The help center recommends that I try and improve my questions.

<s>The question I'm looking to improve is [Virtual Machine vs Virtual Desktop, what is the difference? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295890/virtual-machine-vs-virtual-desktop-what-is-the-difference)</s>

<s>This question has a score of -4 and has been closed due to it been off topic for the site. does anyone have any recommendations of either how I can reword the question so that it is suitable for the site or if there is anything I can do to increase the score so it doesn't reflect negatively on me.</s>

Upon advice I have just deleted the questions as there isn't much hope for it, instead does anyone have any recomendations for this question [swift 4 error handling for URLSession.shared.datatask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481545/swift-4-error-handling-for-urlsession-shared-datatask)

I tried to be specific with what I was asking and only contain relevant information, it has been favorited by a use and has 1 but but I'm not sure how I can improve it.

Comment: Not sure what to recommend for this one as it seems fundamentally unsuited for the site. Do you have any other questions with room for improvement?

Comment: I would strongly suggest burying that question, you're only going to attract more downvotes by linking it here. A quick glance at your profile suggests you have some wiggle room. Work on something you can salvage.

Comment: On top of all that, the two answers are identical, and so likely plagged or spam:(

Comment: Your second liked Q. does not look too bad to me.  I have no swift, so I cannot justify upvoting it myself, (or downvoting it:).

Comment: Deleted Q's still count against Q-block algorithm (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)). If you feel other DV-ed (& closed) Q's can't be improved, show your effort and request unsalvageable Q's to be dissociated.

Comment: About your 2nd question: it's about Swift but it's not specific to Swift 4. You should replace the "swift4" tag with just "swift". Also, please remove the tag from the title. Tags go in the tags section. Titles should only contain a normal sentence/question. And please remove the "xcode" tag, this is not a question about Xcode the IDE. Apart from these details the question looks ok to me.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280870/what-should-a-user-do-with-unsalvageable-questions-when-they-have-been-question