# Reworking the question ban

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users, post-ban, welcoming

[**(Blog Post) - "Stack Overflow Isn't Very Welcoming. It's Time for That to Change."**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

Post bans are arguably the least-welcoming mechanics of Stack Overflow. They work in theory but not in practice. Post bans are supposed to force users to [edit their existing posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/4356188) before they can post new ones. Unfortunately, a lot of users who get into post bans do so by posting off-topic and spammy questions. How can spam be fixed? Off-topic questions will always be off-topic, and [editing questions into completely different ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260066/4356188) is against the rules. Many post-banned users are stuck in a situation that's extremely difficult to escape.

The system was nerfed in 2016 to let post-banned users ask 1 new question every 6 months, but that doesn't really help users climb out of the holes which they dug themselves into. A quote from the block page:

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions/answers which were poorly received.

6 months is a long time. The vast majority of posts on Stack Overflow have scores of 0 and/or 1. Depending on how many bad questions a post-banned user has asked, it can take upwards of YEARS to gather enough upvotes so that the ban finally gets lifted. The current post ban system is simply not constructive.

Stack Overflow's mission is to build a knowledge repository, not to punish people. We should focus on the positive side: maintaining useful, helpful, high-quality content.

**Let's replace hard banning with a system that's more constructive: "post restrictions."** Here's what happens if your contributions are poorly received, triggering a post restriction:

- You can post only 1 new question/answer per week.
- Your submissions aren't visible on the site until they're approved by reviewers.
- Rejected submissions are saved as drafts.
- You can resubmit a rejected submission for reconsideration after editing it and 48 hours have passed since your previous attempt at submission.
- You receive notifications for the reasons why your posts get rejected so you learn from your mistakes.

2 new review queues would be introduced: Restricted Question Submissions and Restricted Answer Submissions, unlocked at 3k reputation.

Post restrictions are lifted the same way as post bans do today:

> The {restriction} will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions/answers which were poorly received.

This new system would encourage posting high-quality questions and answers. Since users have an opportunity to ask a good question and/or post a good answer each week, so they'll never get trapped in a blocked state that takes years to overcome even if their existing posts are simply unsalvageable.

Comment: "[un]welcoming" logically refers to initial entry. The users being banned wore out their welcome.

Comment: The whole point of the question ban is to restrict users who have demonstrated zero ability or willingness to work with the community.  It's **supposed** to be unwelcoming.

Comment: In that suggestion, the curators who closed the bad questions from such a user would be the same curators reviewing incoming questions from restricted users. This is a disincentive towards content curation. Why would you want to increase our workload even more?

Comment: Weekly still feels too frequent. The proposed queues would likely be slammed.

Comment: *You can resubmit a rejected submission for reconsideration after editing it and 24 hours have passed since your previous attempt at submission.* - Shouldn't this also be a week? If you get to resubmit the same post for reconsideration then users will just do this daily instead of starting over with a new post.

Comment: Who are these  'reviewers' of which you speak?  I cannot see many, (any), of the current set of committed and effective curators ever visiting 'triage 2.0' :(  'users have an opportunity to ask a good question and/or post a good answer each week' or, put another way, 'users have an opportunity to dump a no-effort homework dupe every week'.  No thanks.

Comment: **<s>Votes</s> Post ban has nothing to do with being welcoming**. Generally, it's *not* true that [so] is not unwelcoming when it has a feature *you don't like*, but *contributes to [so] mission*.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280870/what-should-a-user-do-with-unsalvageable-questions-when-they-have-been-question

Comment: The restricted q&a review queue would be nothing compared to the close votes queue. Close votes consistently has thousands of pending reviews.

Comment: A person can expend 6 months profiting from all solutions available at SO and in the meantime learning how good questions are made. When the time comes, they will post an excellent question very positively received. Ban ends? When we really, really, want to use a tool, we learn how to use the tool, no?

Comment: @brasofilo 1 excellent question isn't enough to lift the ban. The average question score at SO is 1. A very positively received question could get a score of 5-ish. 10+ score questions are ultra-rare. That alone won't be enough to outweigh the person's other negatively-scored questions. At best, a person would need to ask 3 questions (1.5 years!) for the ban to end.

Comment: Well, they took their time building their ban, to the point of receiving multiple warnings: downvotes, closed/deleted questions, system warnings *"wait, some of your contributions were not well received"*...

Comment: It is accurate, the system by design is extremely unwelcoming by supporting downvotes and post bans.  It mattered a lot to the principal site founder, the site when to hell in a handbasket when he quit in 2012.  But a post ban is a mere formality, a minor rap of the knuckles, it is very easy to evade.  I saw one user brag about having created a new account 18 times to bypass them.  So this doesn't require a major policy change that will get a *lot* of users very upset, and the reason the company can't change it, just a bit of initiative from the users that get into trouble.

Comment: 6 months is somewhat arbitrary of course. It's too long for some users, and way too short for others. Another review queue wouldn't help them I'd think. If we wanted to guide those users, a weekly "question ban helpy help chat" might be an option (though likely tire out contributors quickly).

Comment: @BSMP If the newly proposed queues get slammed then the original 6 month duration will just be a natural product of participation. Heck I foresee their "wait times" becoming indefinite.

Comment: I think these restrictions should be implemented for all new users until they gain a rep of 50.

Comment: @fbueckert If it's not based on reputation, then that's not entirely true. It's really if a user has asked too many "poor" questions that aren't suitable for the site.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Let's replace hard banning with a system that's more constructive

Constructive for *whom*, exactly?

Under your system, the existing userbase would now be invited to review the questions of someone who has repeatedly failed to demonstrate the ability to ask good questions. Time spent reviewing such questions, while helpful towards that person, is not helpful towards the goals of the site. You're asking people, who are already overburdened with maintaining quality on the site, to take on more responsibilities. And that such duties will be primarily devoted to hand-holding users who *repeatedly* violated our community standards in the past.

I do not see how this is a particularly constructive activity. It causes people to spend a great deal of time on a very small portion of our user base, rather than spending their time on the portion of our user base who can actually use the site correctly. And that's not just talking about established users. There are new users who show up all the time and *don't* get question bans.

How constructive is it to have the rest of us devote time to those who couldn't manage to follow our rules? Even after having been warned about their behavior.

There is essentially no reason why an established user would want to use these queues. After all, if nobody reviews those items, they never show up on the site. So what's the point? The site isn't running out of questions, after all.

Please do not mistake "welcoming" for "you're allowed to do anything". When someone proves by their actions that they are not willing to abide by our rules, they are shown the door. That's not being "unwelcoming"; that's dealing with inappropriate behavior.

Comment: I suspect that those who suggest moving the effort of fixing bad questions from the OP's to curators have issued many more upvotes than downvotes, and so would not have to handle much, (if any), of the extra work themselves.  Such suggestions are therefore another: 'needs effort, someone else provide it'.

Comment: Well, it's constructive toward the people that want to change. Most people that wouldn't care would just create a new account anyway, or go against TOS. Also, because of the number of people banned, the review queues wouldn't be that big anyway. 

*How constructive is it to have the rest of us devote time to those who couldn't manage to follow our rules? Even after having been warned about their behavior.*

If they truly want to change, then it helps those people get out of a question ban and gain a learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old post, but I would like to respond to a few points raised here.

> Post bans are supposed to force users to edit their existing posts before they can post new ones.

No, they're primarily intended to prevent further damage to the site by users who habitually post poor content. If they edit their content in order to lift the ban, that's a pleasant side-effect but it's not the main goal.

> Unfortunately, a lot of users who get into post bans do so by posting off-topic and spammy questions. How can spam be fixed?

Why would we want to allow someone who regularly posts unsalvageable spam and off-topic questions to continue to do so?

> You receive notifications for the reasons why your posts get rejected so you learn from your mistakes.

Question closure reasons, the help center and FAQ documentation, and comments on poorly-received posts already do this.

Also, people who are post-banned have already shown that they're unable or unwilling to learn from their mistakes, so I don't see what good that would do.

> 2 new review queues would be introduced: Restricted Question Submissions and Restricted Answer Submissions, unlocked at 3k reputation.

Reviewers are already perpetually overloaded. Reviewing is largely a thankless job that falls on the shoulders of a relatively small number of users who are dedicated to keeping the site clean. It seems rather unfair at best to add even more work in the name of being "welcoming" to people who put forth no effort to contribute positively.

> Stack Overflow's mission is to build a knowledge repository, not to punish people.

While the ban *feel* punitive, it's not primarily intended that way. Again, the main goal is to prevent further damage to the site by users who have shown that they're unwilling or unable to improve.

Being welcoming has to work both ways - users must be willing to learn, improve, and contribute to the community in a positive way. If someone's unwilling or unable to do that, it's not fair to everyone else to allow them to continue to engage in such behavior. Allowing people with a history of posting extremely low-quality content to continue to post creates more work for others and distracts from legitimate content.

Comment: *Why would we want to allow someone who regularly posts unsalvageable spam and off-topic questions to continue to do so?* Wouldn't suspensions do that anyway?

Comment: *If someone's unwilling or unable to do that, it's not fair to everyone else to allow them to continue to engage in such behavior.* Why would someone unwilling to do that submit a question for review after a week? Wouldn't they just create a new account and break TOS (I've seen this before)?