# How to make positive contributions while having an answer ban

Tags: discussion, answers, post-ban

I already tried a few times to answer a question. But every time, I am told I cannot give answers. I checked the history, and it turns out that I have given 3 bad answers over the last 9 years. Mostly by asking the original poster if they already found a solution. I shouldn't have done that, apparently.

The documentation says:

> How can I get out of an answer ban?
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those answers which were poorly received.

But how do I contribute if I cannot give any answer? Not even a good one...

Comment: Do you know the real answers to any of those 3 questions yet? If not you're limited to suggesting edits and asking your own questions.

Comment: @kevinb question bans allow one new question every 6 months, answer bans do not, they are forever.

Comment: "Mostly by asking the original poster if they already found a solution. I shouldn't have done that, apparently." Yes; that's clearly not an answer. Please read [answer] and note well that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @Larnu:  I feel like, for the first time in a long time, that dupe isn't quite correct. Everything in that answer just applies to question bans. Even though they're the most prevalent, this is a case in which that doesn't really apply. I wonder if there is other info about answer bans floating around here.  It doesn't come up often.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel While true, how does that  answer the OP's question now?

Comment: Consider suggesting edits. You maybe able to get some reps from improving others posts, which may or may not help you to get out of a ban.

Comment: I believe the only known route is already covered in the duplicate - edit and undelete your existing posts... @TheMaster - I would be surprised if edits can get on out of q/a ban, but at very least it could get OP ability to comment... so later they can try to appeal to the company that they can actually provide excellent content (with perfect answers in place of currently deleted once and insightful comments)...

Comment: Your account doesn't show as answer-banned so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Dharman Maybe recent rep bump got something to do with that?

Comment: That's possible as they have received 2 upvotes 15 minutes ago

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If the rep bump is the reason, then suggested edits may also have lifted the answer ban. After all, the message is `when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those answers`. Those contributions maybe in any form: good edits, good questions

Comment: *"Everything in that answer just applies to question bans. "* that isn't true though, @Makoto . It called *"What can I do when getting *“We are no longer accepting questions / **answers** from this account”?'* it quotes the message you get when answer banned. It's not just about questions at all.

Comment: @Larnu:  And yet, there's already some conflicting advice about whether or not you can *answer* a question every six months or not.  [Seems like a lot of the weight is on questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370669/1079354)  This would preempt the direct advice in the dupe, especially since it only talks about asking questions.

Comment: @Larnu I believe Makoto's point it answer ban (which apparently forever unlike "serious throttle" for questions) is not explicitly covered in that question. I think CM or mod may want to add official line to that duplicate to clarify answer ban "forever" duration.

Comment: There are some hints by the dev on [an answer to "Does an answer ban allow you to post an answer once every 6 months? Can we make this more clear?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347812/241919)

Comment: Old content needs to time out or weaken over time for banning purposes. Joe Noob might have been a right idiot at 15 but by 25 is changing the world with brilliant insights into coding. And they can't be shared here. That's counterproductive.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the usual duplicate is pretty explicit that you can ask one **question** every six months. It does not say that about answers.

Comment: I still don't get why you persisted asking questions in the answer section a third time after having been told not to do so twice.

Comment: @user4581301 There is a feature request for this, either here or over on https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: In some fairness, the non-answers had 1.5-4 years of space in between them....enough to forget.  It's unfortunate that the system holds a grudge over stuff that occurred in 2013, 2015, and 2019.  Even users who consistently ask horrible questions get another chance every six months.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, if I understood the "Scenario"/Reason correctly, it all comes down from not being able to post Comments for OP: They found the exact Qt (Question) they would want to ask, it has no Answer/Solution, they know if they ask the same Qt it will get downvoted and closed in "no time", they want to avoid that, so they try to post a Comment asking if the "other" Asker found/got a Solution, but the only "place" where they can post a Comment is the 'Answer' Field...

Comment: I... have to admit I'm a bit confused. I only see three answers on your SO profile and while they're all deleted, the system doesn't seem to indicate that you're answer banned... ah, because you're not any more. You were.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: And: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: Better answers, or fixing old ones, are not the only way out of an answer ban: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347809/does-an-answer-ban-allow-you-to-post-an-answer-once-every-6-months-can-we-make#comment1265605_347812

Comment: @chivracq: There are ways to write a new question that demonstrates research effort and can still be well-received when there's an old unanswered duplicate.  e.g. write a better question, and link the old question you already found, pointing out that it's unanswered, especially if it has problems that could have led to it being unanswered (like lack of detail).  [Etiquette for duplicate, yet unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49491) / [Edit unanswered old question or ask my own?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289457) (trying to find more recent / popular meta Q&As)

Comment: [What can you do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253924) is also relevant.  Anyway, presumably the OP didn't know that could work, or didn't want to try it (perhaps in a case where their new question would be identical, so there isn't really an option to ask differently.)

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't expect to unleash such a  discussion. Anyway, one of the moderators lifted the ban, apparently. I could actually answer a question.
Thanks. And I'll think twice before submitting an answer :P

Comment: @JanvanVeldhuizen Nah, these bans can't be lifted by staff or moderators, only by no longer meeting the algorithm that determines whether you should be banned or not. It's generally public information that answer bans are very easy to get out of - it's definitely possible to get stuck for a bit but once unstuck, they're unlikely to reoccur.

Comment: @Jan welcome to meta. The next thing you will be surprised by is how voting works exactly as you don't expect it. Your meta post now is in the +21. If your meta post had been about a question ban... I'm pretty sure it would have been in the -21 or beyond. I think quite some people learned a new thing about how answer bans work because of this post, I did.

Comment: Undelete your repairable answers ASAP!

Answer (score 30):

As the [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans) says,

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those answers which were poorly received.

Positive contributions include:

- Improving other posts by Suggesting edits. This is confirmed by [staff here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347809/does-an-answer-ban-allow-you-to-post-an-answer-once-every-6-months-can-we-make#comment1265605_347812)
- Adding well researched, yet concise questions that are interesting to your peers. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Improving existing answers that aren't deleted. See [How to answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).  If all your answers are deleted and you know the answers to any of those questions, you can edit to fix the answer there with insightful facts and/or code. If the answer was deleted by a moderator, flag that answer requesting undeletion with a custom moderator flag. If it was deleted by the community, ask the community in chat rooms, whether they fit undeletion now. You need a minimum of 20 reps to participate in chat though, in which case, a custom flag or asking  the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) is your only option.

Any reputation gain may contribute to lifting the ban (as it seems in your case). It is apparently [extremely easy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347812) to get a answer only ban lifted. Therefore, this rule

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated

isn't applicable to answer bans. You won't get another chance in 6 months, because it's *extremely easy* to get out of it right now. Start contributing!

Comment: You say "***Any** reputation gain may contribute to lifting the ban*"  This is extremely vague.  What is a reputation gain value that ***guarantees*** such lift?

Comment: @PM77-1 It's vague on purpose. There's no guarantee, because staff/company have decided to keep the actual algorithm a secret. All we know, in this case, is that two upvotes on questions(+20) lifted the ban on a user, whose total rep was 15.

Comment: I'd assume 40k would guarantee a lift.. My 90k seems to be keeping me from beign question banned, despite all my questions being heavily negative.

Comment: So all one needs is a positive meta effect?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yea. But a new user getting positive meta effect? Gods must be on his side! It's extremely lucky for a new user to get positive effect and dodge all meta traps.