# removing horizontal scroll for better readability but edit not meeting requirement

Tags: discussion

[How to get data from old offset point in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935755/how-to-get-data-from-old-offset-point-in-kafka)

there's a horizontal bar in the answer, which should not be a big deal. but if I break the line into 2, it's more readable and does not require you to scroll.

I have read [prevent minor edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255478/prevent-minor-and-invalid-edits-better), does that mean nothing should be done in this scenario?

Comment: Good question. I really hate horizontal scrollbars in code, but I normally don't edit when that is the only issue in the post. I would like to know what the community thinks about this too.

Comment: You're editing a code in answer, which is something that is hard to judge by reviewers. As the editor, you may know that there is nothing wrong if the code is broken into 2 lines, but the reviewers don't know. (some languages are pretty strict with whitespace/linebreak). Also, if that's the only thing you edit, I might reject that as too minor too.

Comment: @AndrewT. that's pretty minor, but I really can't bear the horizontal scroll bar. besides I don't think the code in the question or answer meeting compile standard anyways so really doesn't make a difference.